# I keep getting a keyNotFound coding keys error

Tags: swift

I am using the google books api and I keep getting this error:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "industryIdentifiers", intValue:
> nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
> "items", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue:
> 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "volumeInfo", intValue: nil)],
> debugDescription: "No value associated with key
> CodingKeys(stringValue: "industryIdentifiers", intValue: nil)
> ("industryIdentifiers").", underlyingError: nil))

These are my structs:

```
struct Book: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    let volumeInfo: VolumeInfo
}

struct VolumeInfo: Codable {
    let title, publishedDate: String?
    let authors: [String]?
    let publisher, description: String?
    let imageLinks: ImageLinks?
    let industryIdentifiers: [IndustryIdentifier]
    let averageRating: Double?
    let id: String?
}
// MARK: - IndustryIdentifier
struct IndustryIdentifier: Codable {
    let identifier: String
}

struct ApiResponse: Codable {
    let kind: String
    let totalItems: Int
    let items: [Book]
}

struct ImageLinks: Codable {
    let smallThumbnail, thumbnail: String
}
```

and this is how I'm calling it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
          
 var searchText = "the+deal"
 searchBooks()
        
  }

    func searchBooks() {
            if let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=\(searchText)") {
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                    if let data = data {
                        do {
                            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data)
                            self.bookInfo = response.items
            
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableview.reloadData()
                    }
                    
                }.resume()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Print your JSON, pretty formatted it if needed, but there seems to be a missing value. So you need to handle that case, or at least give us with which `searchText` it failed.

Comment: Paste your JSON into [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) and compare your models to what is generated.

Comment: Basically this error comes when compiler didn't find the specific key in the response. For more detail please share your "search text", which you failed.

Comment: @SatishThakur Just a note, this isn't a compiler error. It's just a thrown & caught error at runtime.

Comment: @Larme I have updated my question and provided the "searchText"

Comment: @SatishThakur I have updated my question and provided the "searchText"

Comment: @Jordan see the below posted answer, if It will not work for you, then please comment.

Comment: @George the error "keyNotFound" is given by swift because in items array at index 2, there is no key named with "industryIdentifiers". We have to handle this using optional or do try catch so that we can avoid crash.

Comment: @SatishThakur It’s not a compiler error though. It’s just an error thrown in Swift

Comment: Yes, absolutely @George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `industryIdentifiers` is an optional value

```
let industryIdentifiers: [IndustryIdentifier]?
```

should fix the issue.